# ubuntu 15.10 Intel Nuc5i5 Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors

Tags: display, intel-graphics, display-resolution, 15.10, intel-nuc

I just did a fresh install of ubuntu 15.10 on my Nuc5i5ryh with a iiyama Prolite B2888UHSU and everytime I boot I get the message "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors".
When I kill the message it puts me back on a undesired resolution, and I have to set the resolution setting up again.

Also when I set up the "Displays" settings , it shows screen resolution that souldn't be there (4:3, 16:10..).

I tried removing monitors.xml just in case, doesn't work.

I had Ubuntu 15.04 just before and I hadn't this error.

I guess it's more of a bug as it is a fresh install..

Many thanks

FYI: Reported the bug there, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1511247

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same problem, having just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm not having any luck in finding a solution.